# Null in not an object (evaluation itemText.style)

Tags: javascript, css, object, null

In a to-do list, I am trying to strike through an item that is checked off, but I am receiving the error -  "Null in not an object (evaluating 'itemText.style')"

Can anyone explain how I should alter this to make the strike-through work?
I'm also trying to avoid putting CSS in my HTML file, if possible.

```
function removeItem() {
    var boxId = this.id.replace("boxId_", "");
    var itemText = document.getElementById("item_", + boxId);
    itemText.style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through"); //error here
}

function addNewItem(list, itemText) {
    totalItems++;

    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
    checkBox.type = "checkbox";
    checkBox.id = "cb_" + totalItems;

    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.id = "item_" + totalItems;
    span.innerText = itemText;
    checkBox.onclick = removeItem;

    listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
    listItem.appendChild(span); 
    list.appendChild(listItem);
}

var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");

var totalItems = 0;
var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
inItemText.focus(); 

btnNew.onclick = function() {
    var itemText = inItemText.value;

    if (!itemText || itemText == "") {
        return false;
    }

    addNewItem(document.getElementById("todoList"), itemText);
};
```

Comment: `var itemText = document.getElementById("item_" + boxId);` - there should not be a coma after `"item_"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of this line

```
var itemText = document.getElementById("item_", + boxId);
```

there is a comma after the closing quotes. Your code basically ignored the `boxId` since it was taken as another parameter which `getElementById` ignored.

make it

```
var itemText = document.getElementById("item_" + boxId);
```